# Get select to same width as a text box in bootstrap rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in rails (4.1.5) using bootstrap (3.3.2). The form has an input textbox and a select. I am using jquery to make the select to be the same width as the textbox.

Here's the strange thing: the width of the select element is being changed by jquery, but it is reading the textbox width and setting the select's width as **167** pixels, whereas the text box in chrome is actually **193** pixels.

Here is `_form.html.erb` :

```
<head>
  <style>
     .form-control {
        width: auto;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<%= form_for foo do |f| %>
    <div class='form-group'><%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name', id: 'foo-name-input', class: 'form-control' %></div>
    <div class='form-group'>      
      <%= f.collection_select(:foo_type, @foo_types.keys.to_a.map{|k|[k.humanize, k]}, :last, :first, {}, {class: 'form-control', id: 'foo-type-select'}) %> 
    </div>
    <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  <% end %>
  <br/>
  <div id='debug-dump'></div>
  ...
  <script>
  $(function () 
  {
    // also tried $('#foo-name-input').show instead of document.ready below, which had the same effect
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#debug-dump').text($('#foo-name-input').width());
      $('#foo-type-select').width($('#foo-name-input').width());
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is based on Dan Short's answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420434/jquery-how-to-get-elements-margin-and-padding) - use outerWidth instead of width as follows to *read* the value, and use width to *write* it:

```
$('#foo-type-select').width($('#foo-name-input').outerWidth());
```