# Stretch content to 100% of container width, minus the width of a floated sibling element

Tags: css

I want to position a dynamic logo (width variable/unknown) next to some content, inside a container (see attached mockup - logo is on the right hand side in green, content is in blue). I specifically want the content div to stretch to the full remaining width of the page as shown in the mockup:

But when I try to float the content to the left and the logo to the right ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdhpy581/)), the logo gets positioned below the content unless I set the content width to less that 100% (and I can't know the content width because the logo width can vary).

[image: layout]

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="logo"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#logo {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px; /*unknown width*/
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}
```

How do I stretch the content div to the full container width, minus the width of the logo?

Comment: since both have unfixed width, then you should go with JavaScript solution, do you need a JS solution (with this you will be able to use the full width available on the window)?

Comment: Can be done with SASS/SCSS... Where you can minus the logo's width from DIV. There you can do the calculation. But here you are using CSS, so the best way to use JS.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your broswer support requirements, `flexbox` can do that

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.content {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1;
}
.logo {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.large {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="logo "></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="logo large"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about browser support., unless you still develop for ancient browsers . Check here http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Support is always worth **mentioning** when dealing with *unknown* requirements on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible approach using **jQuery**:

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/chimos/5qx7zL7q/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var logoWidth = $('#logo').width();
    var docWidth = $(document).width();
    $('#content').width(docWidth-logoWidth);

});
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#content {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#logo {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px; /*unknown width*/
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="logo"></div>
</div>
```

**[Source](http://api.jquery.com/width/)**

---

**EDIT:** Upon the CSS you provided, I added `margin:0;` and `padding:0` to `html,body` to be sure the `document` width represents the actual available space for both DIVs.
In the case that `body` or `html` or the container you use do have `margin`, `padding` or `border`, you can use this code instead of the previous one:

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/chimos/fua24g4L/1/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var logoWidth = $('#logo').width(),
      docWidth = $(document).width(),
      marginB = $('body').outerWidth(true) - $('body').outerWidth(),
      paddingB = $('body').innerWidth() - $('body').width(),
      borderB = $('body').outerWidth() - $('body').innerWidth();

    $('#content').width(docWidth - logoWidth - marginB - paddingB - borderB);

});
```

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7420537/4681687)**