# Get the cursor position on mousedown of inputfield using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sencha-touch-2

I have a input field with some text ( text length is 10 characters ).
I want to get the cursor position where the user has tapped/clicked.

Suppose if user has tapped/clicked at 2 charcter then i want to get the position as 2.

Can anyone help me in achieving this with javascript/secnha/jquery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried yet so far? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field

Answer (score 0):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMsK9/) to see how relative position can be checked via jquery

and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philfreo/MqM76/) to see how to calculate width of input text

so something like (not an executable code, just algo)

```
$( "input-field-selector" ).click( function(){

var positionXRelative = FromFirstFiddle();
var positionXRelative = positionXRelative - padding;
var indexOfClick = positionXRelative/sizeOfCharacterFromSecondFiddle();

} );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @gurvinder372

There are three div's in firstFiddle.
Which method is should consider to get the positionXRelative?

Can you please suggest

Comment: @user3913867 you can try both 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: Thanks again for your quick response.
How to get the 'padding'?

Comment: @user3913867 try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420434/jquery-how-to-get-elements-margin-and-padding