# Position an element using X and Y coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, interact.js

I'm very new to Javascript and I am using InteractJS to make a simple drag and drop of dragging smaller images onto a bigger image. On every drag move event they use the following function:

```
 function dragMoveListener (event) {
    var target = event.target,
        // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

    // translate the element
    target.style.webkitTransform =
    target.style.transform =
      'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

    // update the posiion attributes
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
```

I am assuming that the data-x and and data-y attributes that are set are the position of the element that was just dropped. However, I want to be able to redraw an element in that position. I tried the following:

```
var parent = event.currentTarget;
               var xCoord = parent.getAttribute('data-x');
               var yCoord = parent.getAttribute('data-y');
                $("#testDiv").css({top: parseInt(xCoord + event.dx, 10), left: parseInt(yCoord + event.dy, 10), position: 'absolute'});
```

But this is setting the padding and does not put it in the right position. How can I use the data-x and data-y to position a div/image?

Comment: They use `transform: translate()` to position it, not `top`/`left`, which is not at all the same

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from the parent 
or measure the padding as described here: [jQuery How to Get Element's Margin and Padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420434/jquery-how-to-get-elements-margin-and-padding)
and subtract it from the margin of your #testdiv